# when I compile with csc in Linux，the function JArray.Parse in Newtonsoft.Json with error CS0012

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, json.net, csc

This is the case: I compiled `C#`, using `csc` in Linux. I used Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray in Newtonsoft.Json, and tested the use of JArray.Parse(string). This error was reported during compilation: error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

I tried many ways, but none of them worked... How can I solve this problem? Would anyone like to help me, please?

###### Here is my test code

`Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral`
[TestCode]：

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace test
{
    class JsonTest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            JArray s = JArray.Parse("[" + "\"test!\"" + "]");
            Console.WriteLine(s[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

[And csc test.cs]:

```
> csc -version
3.6.0-4.20224.5 (ec77c100)
> csc -r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll  test.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.6.0-4.20224.5 (ec77c100)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

test.cs(12,31): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference
to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
test.cs(12,24): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference
to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
test.cs(13,31): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference
to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
test.cs(13,13): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference
to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
test.cs(14,31): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference
to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
test.cs(14,36): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference
to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
test.cs(15,31): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference
to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
test.cs(15,31): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference
to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

===============================================================

I tried to introduce netstandard and it compiled, and success!

```
> csc -r:/home/Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll -r:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Facades/netstandard.dll test.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.6.0-4.20224.5 (ec77c100)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

> mono test.exe
test
```

Comment: The error message tells you to add a reference to netstandard, have you tried that? 
> You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard

`csc -r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll -r:netstandard test.cs`

Comment: Just now, I found `netstandard.dll` and imported it, and it compiles, but when I run it, it says another error.
`Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'`

Comment: Is the Newtonsoft.Json.dll file in the same folder as the executable?

Comment: As a follow-up question. Why are you using raw csc, and not the dotnet CLI? The dotnet CLI handles all these technical details for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/

Comment: Yes, the Newtonsoft.Json.dll file is in the same folder. The dotnet CLI does work very well, but since Our Linux only allows me to use the "nobody" user, I can't use "dotnet build" or " dotnet run" properly. It's too hard...

Comment: Your advice saved me a lot of time in my work, and I solved the problem by following your advice. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No problem, good luck! I'll post a summary of my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The version of `Newtonsoft.Json` you're using is based on netstandard. `netstandard` is a framework library that allows libraries, such as newtonsoft to be used with different .NET runtimes.

`csc` requires you to manually specify a reference to the `netstandard` library:

```
csc -r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll -r:netstandard test.cs
```

Also make sure the Newtonsoft.Json.dll is present in the same directory as the resulting executable.

#### Use dotnet CLI if possible

It's not recommended to use `csc` directly. It requires knowledge of the DLLs being used and what framework libraries to reference.

For .NET development on Linux (and also Windows), Microsoft has created the [dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/)